# Have I set up my Android push notifications correctly?

Tags: c#, android, azure, firebase, notifications

I am setting up push notifications in my `Xamarin Forms` app for my `Android` project.  I have been following the online documentation (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/push-notifications/azure/) to get it working but I am having some problems

1 - The notifications don't arrive when I send a test from my Azure `Notification Hub`.
2 - The app crashes during debug after a certain amount of time during the `Register` method.

I believe that the problem is being caused by its registration,  I don't think the registration is working and hence the app times out which causes it to crash and also the Azure Notification Hub sends the message successfully but no device picks it up (possibly because it's not registred)

To start off, here is what I have done so far.

1. I have setup a project in console.firebase.google.com and taken note of the sender ID and the Server Key as instructed.  I have given the Project ID a name of myapp-android-app.
2. I have added all the code from the documtation to my Android project.
3. I have added a GCM notification service to my Notification Hub in Azure and supplied it with the Server Key documented from my Firebase app registration.
4. I have added my google account to my Andoird Emulator

Here is the source code from my Android project.

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;
using Gcm.Client;

namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        //public static MainActivity CurrentActivity { get; private set; }

        // Create a new instance field for this activity.
        static MainActivity instance = null;

        // Return the current activity instance.
        public static MainActivity CurrentActivity
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            instance = this;
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());

            try
            {
                // Check to ensure everything's setup right
                GcmClient.CheckDevice(this);
                GcmClient.CheckManifest(this);

                // Register for push notifications
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Registering...");
                GcmClient.Register(this, PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.SENDER_IDS);
            }
            catch (Java.Net.MalformedURLException)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog("There was an error creating the client. Verify the URL.", "Error");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                CreateAndShowDialog(e.Message, "Error");
            }

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        }
        void CreateAndShowDialog(String message, String title)
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.SetMessage(message);
            builder.SetTitle(title);
            builder.Create().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

**GcmService.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Media;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Util;
using Gcm.Client;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

[assembly: Permission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "@PACKAGE_NAME@.permission.C2D_MESSAGE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.INTERNET")]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK")]
//GET_ACCOUNTS is only needed for android versions 4.0.3 and below
[assembly: UsesPermission(Name = "android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS")]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Permission = Gcm.Client.Constants.PERMISSION_GCM_INTENTS)]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_MESSAGE }, Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_REGISTRATION_CALLBACK }, Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { Gcm.Client.Constants.INTENT_FROM_GCM_LIBRARY_RETRY }, Categories = new string[] { "@PACKAGE_NAME@" })]
    public class PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver : GcmBroadcastReceiverBase<GcmService>
    {
        public static string[] SENDER_IDS = new string[] { "xxxxxxxxxx" };
    }

    [Service]
    public class GcmService : GcmServiceBase
    {
        public static string RegistrationToken { get; private set; }

        public GcmService()
            : base(PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver.SENDER_IDS) { }

        protected override void OnRegistered(Context context, string registrationToken)
        {
            Log.Verbose("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Registered: " + registrationToken);
            RegistrationToken = registrationToken;

            var push = AzureService.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.GetPush();
            MainActivity.CurrentActivity.RunOnUiThread(() => Register(push, null));
        }

        protected override void OnUnRegistered(Context context, string registrationToken)
        {
            Log.Error("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "Unregistered RegisterationToken: " + registrationToken);
        }

        protected override void OnError(Context context, string errorId)
        {
            Log.Error("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Error: " + errorId);
        }

        public async void Register(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Push push, IEnumerable<string> tags)
        {
            try
            {
                const string templateBodyGCM = "{\"data\":{\"message\":\"$(messageParam)\"}}";

                JObject templates = new JObject();
                templates["genericMessage"] = new JObject
                {
                    {"body", templateBodyGCM}
                };

                await push.RegisterAsync(RegistrationToken, templates);
                Log.Info("Push Installation Id", push.InstallationId.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Info("PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver", "GCM Message Received!");

            var msg = new StringBuilder();

            if (intent != null && intent.Extras != null)
            {
                foreach (var key in intent.Extras.KeySet())
                    msg.AppendLine(key + "=" + intent.Extras.Get(key).ToString());
            }

            // Retrieve the message
            var prefs = GetSharedPreferences(context.PackageName, FileCreationMode.Private);
            var edit = prefs.Edit();
            edit.PutString("last_msg", msg.ToString());
            edit.Commit();

            string message = intent.Extras.GetString("message");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
            {
                CreateNotification("New todo item!", "Todo item: " + message);
            }

            string msg2 = intent.Extras.GetString("msg");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg2))
            {
                CreateNotification("New hub message!", msg2);
                return;
            }

            CreateNotification("Unknown message details", msg.ToString());
        }

        void CreateNotification(string title, string desc)
        {
            // Create notification
            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

            // Create an intent to show the UI
            var uiIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

            // Create the notification
            // we use the pending intent, passing our ui intent over which will get called
            // when the notification is tapped.
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            var notification = builder.SetContentIntent(PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, 0))
                    .SetSmallIcon(Android.Resource.Drawable.SymActionEmail)
                    .SetTicker(title)
                    .SetContentTitle(title)
                    .SetContentText(desc)
                    .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification)) // set the sound
                    .SetAutoCancel(true).Build(); // remove the notification once the user touches it

            // Show the notification
            notificationManager.Notify(1, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

I replaced the string in: `public static string[] SENDER_IDS = new string[] { "xxxxxxxx" };` with the `Sender` id I recorded from my Firebase console app.

When I run the app through my Android Emulator I get the following error after about 3 minutes.

Error in **GcmService.cs**:

```
Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

seen at Line 71:

```
await push.RegisterAsync(RegisteToken, templates);
```

Does anyone know what I have done wrong? Am I correct in thinking that it's not registering correctly?

Comment: It seems your registration operation failed after a period of time. I assumed that it could be a network issue, you could capture the network traces from your emulator via fiddler to narrow this issue.

Comment: Thanks @BruceChen I didn't see anything obvious when I checked.  Is there anything else I can do, I'm tearing my hair out and there is no good solid info about what is going wrong, just the time out.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging in Xamarin.Forms (both Android and iOS) following this official Xamarin guide that is well explained:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/

Looking at your code, it seems to me that you use the old Gcm service (that is deprecated) and not the new Fcm.
You should have a *google-services.json* file and a *FirebaseMessagingService* class

Then...

> Note
>
> As of now, Xamarin Forms does not handle very well the deployment of the app while developing, making a dirty reinstallation that seems to *invalidate* the previously obtained *Notification Token* and sometimes raising *IllegalStateException* when calling Fcm library's methods.
>
> That's a known bug that can be resolved by cleaning the solution and
>   relaunching